# delete chrome cache via comandline

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem understanding the Chrome Cache in a project on a local computer.

the project is rendered via Express or http-server server with the Chrome Server full screen.

Chrome is started via batch file, the app then preloads the essential data.

start chrome -disable-pinch --force-device-scale-factor=1.0 -start-fullscreen -kiosk http://127.0.0.1:8080

the website data is updated from various sources. I want to be sure that the current data is loaded after every restart of the browser.

how can I delete the cache via commanline, or which strategy is the right one here.

discussion